# Obtaining the entire extent of a Voronoi diagram as polygons

Tags: python, voronoi-thiessen

I am trying to create a shapefile from a voronoi diagram. Here is the snippet of code used to produce the diagram..

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

# Array of coordinates
systematic_coords = np.array([[-3.84578106e+04, 9.16221259e+06],
                              [2.82218936e+03, 9.18528259e+06],
                              [2.82218936e+03, 9.16221259e+06],
                              [2.82218936e+03, 9.13914259e+06]..])

# create voronoi diagram
vor = Voronoi(systematic_coords)

# plot the diagram
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
```

[image]

And here is what I am using to produce valid polygons from the diagram..

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# extract valid polygons
voronoi_polygons = [Polygon(vor.vertices[region]) for region in vor.regions if region and -1 not in region]

# convert to geodataframe
out = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polygons, crs=src.crs)
```

[image]

I would like my shapefile to retain a polygon for every coordinate, but it appears that certain polygons (those with the dotted lines in the diagram) are being dropped out. How can I prevent this, and ensure that my shapefile comes out looking like the voronoi diagram?

Here is a link to a similar post - [Making polygon for every point in set using Voronoi diagram](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337561/making-polygon-for-every-point-in-set-using-voronoi-diagram). A solution was provided but I was wondering if there might be a better way to solve this issue.

Comment: The idea in the post you've linked looks pretty good. The missing polygons are ones which go off to infinity so you have to chop them somewhere...

Comment: I'd polygonaize vor.ridges and convexhull of points